# About const pointer and parameter-passing in CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nvidia

How nvcc handle const pointers in kernels?

According to nvidia, adding const and **restrict** for pointers during parameter-passing enable NVCC for aggressive optimizations, is this strictly following the C/C++ way?

Assuming A is pointer pointed to a buffer of data which will be freqenently updated by maybe other threads/streams, but the contents will not get modified during this test kernel call:

```
test<<<blocks, threads>>>(const int *__restrict__ A, int *__restrict__ B);
```

Then can NVCC maintain correctness of this: load the updated data in A at each kernel call, instead of loading some pre-cached out-dated data?

Comment: C++ doesn't even have a `restrict` keyword, so it is following C99 rather than C++.  But generally, potential aliasing kills optimization.

Comment: Also, if the data is updated from other threads, shouldn't you have made it `volatile` or include a memory barrier in some other way?  That's certainly required in CPU-side C and C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the data is modified by other threads but wont be modified at and during the time of this kernel call, I dont think I need volatile here (In my case, there is a global flag across all threads to control this, but thats CPU side stuff), as for restrict, it is a NVCC recongized keyword.

Comment: const means "treat this object as read-only in this scope". Compilers can usually detect usage that conflicts with this modifier. restrict means "this pointer is the only path through which the pointed to object will be accessed in this scope". It is an assertion the programmer makes and that a compiler in general cannot verify. If the programmer breaks their promise (i.e. there is in fact aliasing) the code is bound not to work as the programmer desired. Since C++ (even in its 2011 incarnation) does not support restricted pointers, CUDA follows C99 but uses the keyword __restrict__.

Answer (score 5):

`const` works like C++. A `const` variable cannot be changed and this is checked at compile time by the compiler. Compiler checks const-correctness only for the given scope as constness can be changed with C style casts.

`restrict` works in the C way. When you mark pointers as restrict compiler assumes these pointers are not aliased. This is your given fact and compiler won't check if this fact is true or not.

Coming to your question, NVCC won't make sure correctness of global memory writes and reads between kernel launches. Since kernel launches are asynchronous in CUDA you have to be sure kernels modifying these memory spaces are not executed at the same time. You can achieve this through synchronous memory copies and/or `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`. If you launch these kernels at the same time there is no way to make sure all changes by different kernels are committed to global memory before accesses from other kernels.